# How to get Milestone Name in Trigger for Entitlement process?

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there any way we can query and get the `Milestone name` based on `CaseMilestone object` details ? I have a trigger and I want to dynamically pass the MileStone name value instead of doing hard-coding as shown below. Any pointers ?

```
public class CompleteMilesone {

    public static void completeMilestoneDate(List<SObject> newSobjs, Map<Id,SObject> oldSobjsMap){
        ...........
        ..........
        ..........
        ...........

        if(!caseIds1.isEmpty())
            MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds1, 'ABC', System.now());
        else if(!caseIds2.isEmpty())
             MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds2,'XYZ', System.now());
    }
}
```

I tried below query,

```
SELECT AssetId,CasesPerEntitlement,EndDate,Id,Name,Status,Type FROM Entitlement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve Milestone Name you need to execute this query

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM MilestoneType 
where Id IN 
(SELECT MilestoneTypeId 
FROM CaseMilestone 
WHERE CaseId = '<case id>')
```

Comment: Thanks, How you calculate such a nice query? This works fine